# Does make sense to use t-SNE and then applied HDBSCAN to cluster?

Tags: clustering, tsne

I believe that the title is self-contained. Does make sense to use t-SNE and then applied HDBSCAN to cluster the data with dimensionality reduction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tSNE is **NOT** a **Dimensionality Reduction** algorithm but a **Visualization** method](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/96947/8878).

The reason is that it is non-parametric and can not model a new data in the same way. What you are looking for is [UMAP](https://pair-code.github.io/understanding-umap/) and yes, you can reduce dimensionality and use a clustering method to find clusters (indeed this is a common practice in clustering)